# How calculate prediction accuracy of OneVsRestClassifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

how I can calculate the prediction Accuracy and F1 Score of OneVsRestClassifier?

```
>>> from sklearn import datasets
>>> from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
>>> from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
>>> iris = datasets.load_iris()
>>> X, y = iris.data, iris.target
>>> OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(random_state=0)).fit(X, y).predict(X)
```

Comment: @FlorianH see [Possible duplicate question in another (programming) language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319542/3005167)

Comment: @kazemakase Thanks, i missed that, removed the possible dublicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accuracy, precision, and recall for multi-class model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081702/accuracy-precision-and-recall-for-multi-class-model)

Comment: Before rushing to open a question here, please ensure that at least you have read the relevant [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sklearn's metrics module.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
model = OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(random_state=0))
model.fit(X, y)
yhat = model.predict(X)

print('Accuracy:', accuracy_score(y, yhat))
print('F1:', f1_score(y, yhat, average='micro'))
```

Note that I set the `average` argument to `micro`. You can change this based on the options [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html).